# Rerun entire code if error Cannot choose from an empty sequence occurs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to coding so please bear with me.

[image]

If you look at the image, I have 3 workers and 3 stations where true means that the worker is trained for the station and false means that the worker is not.
Now, what my code does is that, it chooses a random choice between all the true for the first station. Then it eliminates that option for the next station and then chooses a random choice from all the Trues for the next station and so on.
Now, there is a possibility that, because of random choices, the code has no options left as all the true have been used before and the rest are false. In this case, it gives me an error "Cannot choose from an empty sequence".
Now, what I want is that, I want to have a way (maybe an if statement) which says if 'error occurs' then rerun the whole code. So, this way I would end up not getting an error as it would rerun until I do not get an error. I am not sure if this is even possible in python.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A better solution to your problem would be to fix the error. Can you provide us information about the exact error and the code you´ve written?

Comment: Please work through [a basic Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). Exception handling is a very common, fundamental operation in Python.

Comment: Please do not post code or example input as images – post them as code-formatted text. Links may rot over time, and requiring volunteers to re-type your code and input will greatly reduce your chances of getting help. See the [ask] and [mcve] pages for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use **try / except** like this:

```py
try:
     random.choice
except:
    pass
```

So if **try** section runs without errors, **random.choice** will be execute but if occur an error, **except** section execute and it just **pass** and your code continues.

Comment: You might want to expand on this example. ``random.choice`` will only fail if ``random`` was not imported, a bare ``except`` clause is generally considered an anti-pattern (it will catch various unrelated Exceptions, such as closing the application); finally, using ``pass`` without a loop does not match the desired behaviour of retrying on failure.

Comment: I have updated my question which now explains why I get the error with random.choice. Hopefully it is understandable to you